# How to add activity indicator to navbar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uiactivityindicatorview

Hey, I want to display an activity indicator on the right corner of my navbar when my user changes selection in picker wheel. I have no idea how to add activity indicator there I am only able to add normal navbar buttons there. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator =  
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];  
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                         initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];  
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barButton];  

[barButton release];  
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

This should work.
From: http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/adding-an-activity-indicator-spinner-to-navigation-bar.html